How do i use a spark session or spark context inside a UDF which will be applied in parallel for every row in a partition using foreachpartitions?
My requirement is to get some of the column values from the row of a partitioned spark dataframe and use it to calculate a variable (by joining dataframes A,B,C,D,E filtering and sorting) and then insert the calculated value into dataframes (A,B,C) which will then be written to S3. Now when the next row is to be processed, the updated data from A, B, C ong with D and E will be used for calculating.
For this I am using a for loop, the partitioned_dataframe is set to have around 1000 rows.
Now when applying the UDF (which has the For loop, variable calculation and S3 writes) to the partitioned dataframe using foreach partition I am getting this error:

File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 686, in main
process()
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 676, in process
out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 540, in func
File "/tmp/check test 5-Spark-V2.py", line 221, in 
File "/tmp/check test 5-Spark-V2.py", line 65, in process_partition
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 269, in getOrCreate
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 491, in getOrCreate
SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 186, in init
SparkContext._assert_on_driver()
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1541, in _assert_on_driver
raise RuntimeError("SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.")
RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.

Below is the UDF that I am using:
def write_to_s3(df, file_key):
    # Define the S3 output path
    output_path = f"s3://bucket/{file_key}"

    # Write the DataFrame to S3 in CSV format
    df.write \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .csv(output_path)

    print(f"DataFrame successfully written to S3 bucket with file path: {output_path}")

def read_from_s3(file_key):
    # Define the S3 input path
    input_path = f"s3://bucket/{file_key}"

    try:
        # Read the CSV file directly from S3 into a Spark DataFrame
        df = spark.read \
            .format("csv") \
            .option("header", "true") \
            .load(input_path)

        print("DataFrame successfully created from the CSV file.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None
    
    return df

# defining the function to be applied to each row
def transform_partition(partition):
    for row in partition:
        print(row)
        try:
            var_invoptdest_source = row['source']
            var_invoptdest_dest = row['dest']
            var_invoptdest_item = row['item']
            var_invoptdest_major = row['majorshipqty']
            var_invoptdest_minor = row['minorshipqty']
            var_invoptdest_need = row['need_remain_qty']
            var_invoptsource_source = row['source_src']
            var_invoptsource_item = row['item_src']
            var_invoptsource_excess = row['excess_src']
            
            static_inv_opt_network_df= read_from_s3('SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/static_inv_opt_network_df.csv')
            inv_opt_dest_df= read_from_s3('SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_dest_df.csv')
            vw_by_sku_sourcing_df= read_from_s3('SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/vw_by_sku_sourcing_df.csv')
            inv_opt_source_df= read_from_s3('SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_source_df.csv')
            inv_opt_output_df= read_from_s3('SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_output_df.csv')
            
            # Add suffixes to column names
            static_inv_opt_network_df_1 = static_inv_opt_network_df.select([col(c).alias(c + '_ion') for c in static_inv_opt_network_df.columns])
            inv_opt_dest_df_1 = inv_opt_dest_df.select([col(c).alias(c + '_iod') for c in inv_opt_dest_df.columns])
            inv_opt_source_df_1 = inv_opt_source_df.select([col(c).alias(c + '_ios') for c in inv_opt_source_df.columns])
            
            # Perform joins with updated column names
            merged_df_1 = static_inv_opt_network_df_1.join(inv_opt_dest_df_1, static_inv_opt_network_df_1['dest_ion'] == inv_opt_dest_df_1['dest_iod'])
            merged_df_2 = merged_df_1.join(vw_by_sku_sourcing_df, (merged_df_1['item_iod'] == vw_by_sku_sourcing_df['item']) & (merged_df_1['dest_iod'] == vw_by_sku_sourcing_df['dest']))
            merged_df_3 = merged_df_2.join(inv_opt_source_df_1, (merged_df_2['source_ion'] == inv_opt_source_df_1['source_ios']) & (merged_df_2['item_iod'] == inv_opt_source_df_1['item_ios']))
            
            # Rename columns to remove leading/trailing whitespaces
            merged_df_3 = merged_df_3.select([col(c).alias(c.strip()) for c in merged_df_3.columns])
            
            # Apply filters
            filtered_df_1 = merged_df_3.filter(
                (merged_df_3['active_ion'] == 'Y') &
                (merged_df_3['need_remain_qty_iod'] >= merged_df_3['majorshipqty_iod']) &
                (merged_df_3['majorshipqty_iod'] <= merged_df_3['excess_orig_qty_ios']) &
                (merged_df_3['dest_iod'] == var_invoptdest_dest) &
                (merged_df_3['source_ion'] == var_invoptsource_source) &
                (merged_df_3['item_iod'] == var_invoptsource_item) &
                (merged_df_3['majorshipqty_iod'] == var_invoptdest_major) &
                (merged_df_3['minorshipqty_iod'] == var_invoptdest_minor)
            )
            
            # Extract the excess_orig_qty into the variable var_computed_excess
            var_computed_excess = filtered_df_1.select('excess_orig_qty_ios').first()[0] if filtered_df_1.count() > 0 else None
            
            # Check if var_computed_excess is not None and greater than 0
            if var_computed_excess is not None and var_computed_excess > 0:
                var_outputQty = 0
                # Check if var_computed_excess is greater than or equal to var_invoptdest_need
                if var_computed_excess >= var_invoptdest_need:
                    # Calculate var_outputqty
                    var_outputqty = (var_invoptdest_need // var_invoptdest_major * var_invoptdest_major) + \
                                    (var_invoptdest_need % var_invoptdest_major // var_invoptdest_minor * var_invoptdest_minor)
                else:
                    # Calculate var_outputqty
                    var_outputqty = (var_computed_excess // var_invoptdest_major * var_invoptdest_major) + \
                                    (var_computed_excess % var_invoptdest_major // var_invoptdest_minor * var_invoptdest_minor)
            
                # Check if var_outputqty is greater than or equal to var_min_transfer_qty
                var_min_transfer_qty = 2
                if var_outputqty >= var_min_transfer_qty:
                
                    # Add values to inv_opt_output_df
                    inv_opt_output_df = inv_opt_output_df.union(
                                        spark.createDataFrame([(var_invoptsource_source, var_invoptdest_dest, var_invoptdest_item, var_outputqty)], 
                                        ['source', 'dest', 'item', 'qty'])
                                        )
                
                    # Update inv_opt_dest_df
                    inv_opt_dest_df = inv_opt_dest_df.withColumn('need_remain_qty', 
                                                                 when((col('dest') == var_invoptdest_dest) & (col('item') == var_invoptdest_item),
                                                                      col('need_remain_qty') - var_outputqty)
                                                                 .otherwise(col('need_remain_qty')))
                
                    # Update inv_opt_source_df
                    inv_opt_source_df = inv_opt_source_df.withColumn('excess_remain_qty',
                                                                     when((col('source') == var_invoptsource_source) & (col('item') == var_invoptdest_item),
                                                                          col('excess_remain_qty') - var_outputqty)
                                                                     .otherwise(col('excess_remain_qty')))
                    
                    write_to_s3(inv_opt_source_df,'SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_source_df.csv')
                    write_to_s3(inv_opt_dest_df,'SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_dest_df.csv')
                    write_to_s3(inv_opt_output_df,'SCM_Analytics/inv_opt_test/inv_opt_output_df.csv')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    
try:
    
    # Read partitioned data from S3
    partitioned_df = spark.read \
    .option("basePath", "s3://bucket/path/") \
    .csv("s3://bucket/path/")
    
    # Process each partition in parallel
    partitioned_df.foreachPartition(lambda partition: map(transform_partition, partition))

Please suggest how I can resolve this error. Or if there is any alternate method to implement the same logic.
How do I use a spark session or spark context inside a UDF which will be applied in parallel for every row in a partition using foreach partitions?
Is it possible? How to handle such scenarios using spark in glue
